# How to make javascript only accept the given regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, spring, forms

I'm trying to make a form in javascript to register an user, and one of the fields is the phone number.

I have a few patterns that the phone number must follow

it must contain a "+" followed by a number from 1 to 999 then "(" then a number from 1 to 999 then ")" and then at least 4 digits from 0 to 9.

or

A "+" followed by a number from 1 to 999 and then at least 4 digits from 0 to 9

or

at least 4 digits from 0 to 9.

You can save in the form any phone number, but if the one you introduce is different from those patterns, then a message should appear to warn you about that (the warning part works).

This is the javascript function I made

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPhone() {
        var numberPattern1 = new RegExp("\\+[0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{4,}");
        var numberPattern2 = new RegExp("\\+[0-9]{1,3}\\([0-9]{1,3}\\)[0-9]{4,}");
        var numberPattern3 = new RegExp("[0-9]{4,}");
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
        var test1 = numberPattern1.test(phone.value);
        var test2 = numberPattern2.test(phone.value);
        var test3 = numberPattern3.test(phone.value);
        var match = test1 || test2 || test3;
        if (!match) {
            var test = alert("<spring:message code = 'number.dont.match'/>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the part of the form where I call that function

```
<form:label path="phone">
        <spring:message code="reviewer.phone" />:
    </form:label>
    <form:input path="phone" id="phone" onChange="checkPhone()" />
    <form:errors cssClass="error" path="phone" />
```

I expect it to accept strings like these (and the code accepts them)

```
+23758976540
+456(542)3845
987645907
6543
+66734
+567(1)9388
```

and also make a warning with strings like these

```
456
fsdfsdfhge
+0(0)4567
+65(4956)3456
```

The problem is that it's not warning me when I type things like

```
+1234 //(it should have at least one more digit)
++1245
+65(4956)3456 //(Can't have more than 3 numbers in the parenthesis)
+0(0)4567 //(the number after the "+" and from the parenthesis must be at least 1)
aaaaaaaaaa8888aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa+45(867)86543
jguosfoafos+339999oiajdiajdsi
```

It looks like it match any string as long as it has 4 digits together, like the last pattern, I think the problem is due to the regular expression, but I'm not too sure.
What should I do to get a warning if the WHOLE string don't match a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the RegEx to account for the start and end of a string using `^` and `$`:

```
function checkPhone() {
    var numberPattern1 = new RegExp("^\\+[0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{4,}$");
    var numberPattern2 = new RegExp("^\\+[0-9]{1,3}\\([0-9]{1,3}\\)[0-9]{4,}$");
    var numberPattern3 = new RegExp("^[0-9]{4,}$");
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    var test1 = numberPattern1.test(phone.value);
    var test2 = numberPattern2.test(phone.value);
    var test3 = numberPattern3.test(phone.value);
    var match = test1 || test2 || test3;
    if (!match) {
        var test = alert("<spring:message code = 'number.dont.match'/>");
    }
}
```

---

### Example:

```js
    function checkPhone(phone) {
        var numberPattern1 = new RegExp("^\\+[0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{4,}$");
        var numberPattern2 = new RegExp("^\\+[0-9]{1,3}\\([0-9]{1,3}\\)[0-9]{4,}$");
        var numberPattern3 = new RegExp("^[0-9]{4,}$");
        var test1 = numberPattern1.test(phone);
        var test2 = numberPattern2.test(phone);
        var test3 = numberPattern3.test(phone);
        var match = test1 || test2 || test3;
        if (!match) {
            var test = alert("<spring:message code = 'number.dont.match'/>");
        }
    }
    
    checkPhone("+1234");
```

Comment: @rayo329: This is matching `+0000000000000000`, `000000000000`, `+0(0)0000000000000000000000`

Comment: @Toto right, but that's what the RegEx states to do. If the OP had an issue with length the end of all of them wouldn't be `{ 4 , }`

Comment: OP said: 'it must contain a "+" followed by a number from 1 to 999 then "(" then a number from 1 to 999 then ")" ', the first number shouldn't be `0`

Comment: @Toto I see what you mean, unfortunately I'm unable to delete this answer but I'll try to update it later. Surprising the OP didn't point it out as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Regex test function tries to find regex pattern in given string, it may substring. To match whole string, you can specify start('^') and finish('$') characters in beginning and ending of regex.

So your patterns should look like

```
"^\\+[0-9]{1,3}[0-9]{4,}$"
"^\\+[0-9]{1,3}\\([0-9]{1,3}\\)[0-9]{4,}$"
"^[0-9]{4,}$"
```

Refer https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors